# Is it possible to select a node that just includes a subset of the child nodes?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have some XPath:

```
//tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[position() > 1]
```

Which gives me everything but the first child node. However, it gives me a nodelist of td notes as a result. I want to select the parent tr node, but with the first child td node removed.

Is this possible using just xpath?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and complete, short and easy solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**XPath is a query language for XML documents. As such it cannot modify the structure the source XML document or create a new XML document.**

The task of creating a new, modified document cannot be done with XPath only.

**This is easy to accomplish with XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tr[2]/td[1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**the wanted, correct result (all nodes copied with the exception of the 1st `<td>` child of the second `<tr>`) is produced:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```